# Saving child form before parent form submission

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a parent component `A` which allows users to edit data of a resource `item` and a child component `B` which allows users to edit/add multiple related entries of `item` - `relateditem`. Like so:

component A:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  template: `
    <!-- form editing --> 
    <b-component [itemPk]="item.pk"></b-component>
    <button (click)="saveA()">Save</button>`,
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  item: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('item').subscribe((item) => (this.item = item));
  }

  saveA() {
    return this.http.post('item', this.item);
  }
}
```

component B:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'b-component',
  template: `
    <!-- form editing -->
    <button (click)="saveB()">Save Related</button>
  `,
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() itemPk: any;
  relatedItems: any[];
  error: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get(`item/${this.itemPk}/related`)
      .subscribe((relatedItems) => (this.relatedItems = relatedItems));
  }

  saveB() {
    this.http.post(`item/${this.itemPk}/related`, this.relatedItems).subscribe({
      next: () => {},
      error: (error) => {this.error = error}
    });
  }
}
```

In my structure, users can save entries of `relatedItems` independently - without saving entries of the parent `item` - they just click on "Save" in `b-component`.

What I am trying to achieve is that when save is clicked on `A` to save the parent level `item` entry, it will first save the current changes in the `relatedItem` entries in `B` before doing so. i.e:

1. User clicks save in `AComponent`
2. `BComponent.save()` is called
3. `AComponent` waits for `BComponent` to finish saving
4. If `BComponent` saves successfully then `AComponent` then continues the save, else it stops if there is an error.

I know that `AComponent` can obtain a reference to `BComponent` and call the method directly like so:

Component A:

```
...

@ViewChild(BComponent) bcomponent: BComponent;

...

saveA() {
    this.bcomponent.saveB().subscribe(() => this.saveA());
}

...
```

But this feels wrong to me for a few reasons:

1. In my simplified example B is a direct parent of A, but in my real world scenario B is several children deep - I would have to expose a method for each component on the way.
2. Parents having to call methods of children seems wrong, especially coming over from Vue. It feels like I am not utilising the framework correctly.
3. `BComponent.save()` returns a subscription, so `AComponent` can't actually do `bcomponent.save().subscribe`. I could make another method of `BComponent` which returns `http.post` directly, but `BComponent` needs to be subscribed to the POST request so it can assign `this.error` if needed.

What is the framework ideal way of achieving this?

Comment: You could do something like have a service, and when the children are created, they register themselves with the service. Then when the parent wants to save, it calls some `save` method on the service. The service could then access all the registered children, call and call `save` on them. Then the children's `save` could return a promise, and the service would just need to `Promise.all` to wait for them all to complete.